# Integers $n$ such that $n^d + (n+1)^d$ is never prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, computability-theory

Let us call an integer $n>0$ *pure* if for all integers $d>0$ we have that $n^d + (n+1)^d$ is not prime. Is the set of pure integers non-empty? Is it [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_set)?

Comment: $n^d+(n+1)^d$ is surely composite if $d$ is not a power of 2. So, one can restrict attention to the case $d=2^k$. That is, $n$ is pure iff the corresponding [generalized Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Generalized_Fermat_numbers) are all composite.

Comment: You may also check the [factorisation of fermat numbers](http://www.sspectra.com/math/GenFermat11.txt)

Comment: The OP is allowing d to be 1, so the smallest candidate for purity, according to OEIS, is 28

Comment: @paulMonsky: Good point! Then a bettert OEIS reference is [A057856](https://oeis.org/A057856), which by the way states a conjecture implying that there are no pure numbers.